# Generate form for array with hashes with formtastic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash, formtastic

I'm having difficulty with formtastic. I'll first try to sketch the situation as good as I can.

I have a model named `onlinescore` which has attributes `publisher`, `id`, and some other basic ones. One of its attributes however is an array with `urls`. Those `urls` are hashes with content like this:

```
{"url" => "http://www.example.com", "description" => "blabla"}
```

So the array looks like this:

```
[{"url" => "http://www.example0.com", "description" => "blabla0"},
{"url" => "http://www.example1.com", "description" => "blabla1"},
{"url" => "http://www.example2.com", "description" => "blabla2"}]
```

I'm now making a form to create a new `onlinescore` and for that I need a way to collect input for that array. I'd like to have 2 fields ("url" and "description") who get mapped into the urls array somehow. Once that works, I would want the user to be able to add several urls at once, for example with an 'add new url' button which generates another 2 of those fields.

I already tried to accomplish this on some ways for example like this:

```
#rest of form
<% @onlinescore.url.each do |link| %>
  <% form.inputs :for => link do |urls| %>
    <%= urls.input :url, :as => :url %>
    <%= urls.input :description, :as => :string %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
#rest of form
```

which gives the error:

> undefined method `model_name' for Hash:Class

I also tried to define a new input type :score_url but I didn't get far with that either because I need a tuple of 2 fields, not one and I didn't find a way to do that yet. I looked into forms without a model, but I don't really think that is what I need either...

Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here (and the cause of the 'undefined method `model_name' for Hash:Class' error) is that each url you're trying to create a set of fields for is a Hash, not an ActiveRecord or ActiveModel model. If you could represent those items as an array of models, instead of an array of hashes, I think you'd be fine. Formtastic works best with models. Rails is a framework that does the same. A Hash will not work here sorry, there's too much Formtastic and Rails expect to be able to call on each item.